# "Allows not" vs. "does not allow"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, negation, do-support

Which should I use: *allows not* or *does not allow*?

Can I use both?

Are there verbs that does not allow the two forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Allows not* is archaic. There is also a small problem with word order and where the object of the verb goes. These days it is only used for particular [effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton).

There are only two verbs in modern English whose present tense is always negated by following with *not*: *do* and *be*.

> He does not...
>   He is not...

Every other verb uses "do not" to negate it: "He does not allow..." as opposed to "He allows not". The second form is used only for effect.

As Barrie has commented, *have* is also a modal verb along with *do* and *be*, and it can also be negated by following it with *not*. There is [some evidence*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+not+a%2Cdoes+not+have+a%2Chas+not+the%2Cdoes+not+have+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that generally it isn't nowadays when the verb has a stated object. Where the object is stated, it's usually treated the same as every other verb.

> He has not.
>   He does not have it.
>   He has it not. [Not generally used]

<sub>* Because "Has not...?" is a reasonable way of constructing a question, the Ngram is not *entirely* conclusive.</sub>

Comment: I think you need to look up [hyperbaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton).

Comment: @Robusto Did I not cover that with my third sentence? That was my intention.

Comment: All modal verbs are negated by an immediately following 'not'. 'Have' can be, too, in its contracted form.

Comment: @BarrieEngland You're right. One can over-simplify. *Have* has a foot in both camps.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically acceptable, but "does not allow" sounds more natural in American English.  "Allows not" could sound pretentious or out of place.

> The law allows not stealing.
>
> The law does not allow stealing.