# Inversion in "Only when the virus introduces its nucleic acid into a cell does disease occur"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns, subject-verb-inversion

Given this sentence,

> Disease occurs only when the virus introduces its nucleic acid into a cell.

Is the following inversion grammatical?

> → Only when the virus introduces its nucleic acid into a cell does disease occur.

Especially the "does disease occur" part.

I think that "occurs disease " is right. Can you explain a rule about this kind of sentence?

Comment: *"Only when someone dies has murder occurred"* - credible. *"Only when someone dies occurred murder"* - ***not*** credible (except in [Yoda speak](http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/)).

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is right.

A simple way of looking at the rule of *inversion* is thinking about question and sentence patterns in English.

The question pattern is:

```
Verb (V) + Subject (S)
```

Some learners actually misunderstand the meaning of "*v*." In the same way that these questions are wrong and unacceptable:

> Went he to school?
>
> Like you strawberries?

Your alternative is also wrong:

> Occurs disease?

I pointed out these things because the pattern for *inversion* is the same pattern for questions. And this pattern is:

```
Auxiliary Verb + Subject + Main Verb
```

So,

Only when... **does disease occur**. = OK

Comment: Small question... isn't "have you a towel?" acceptable? What is the difference between this and "like you strawberries?" Is is applicable only for the verb 'have'?

Comment: *Have* is a special case with "a foot in both camps" as I said with [a very similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74757/allows-not-vs-does-not-allow)

Comment: @asymptotically I’d say “Have you a towel?” is at best marginally acceptable. It’s grammatical, but nobody ever says that. They say either “Do you have a towel?” or perhaps more commonly, “Have you got a towel?”, sometimes shortened to simply “Got a towel?”.

Comment: "Have you a towel?" is grammatical, but at least one grammar textbook says it's "less usual." The same with "I haven't a towel."

Comment: No problem. The source I got that from is British btw

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different cases where inversion is permissible.  There's a really good list at http://esl.about.com/od/advancedgrammar/a/inversion.htm.  There are sentences with the structure that you've exhibited, using "only", on this list.  There's more detail available about this particular case at http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv34.shtml.

The key point with inversion is that there are are only a limited number of verbs that can come before the subject when you use inversion - just modal verbs and auxiliary verbs.  So, you can invert "does" (that is, put it before "disease", as per your example).  But you can't invert "occurs".