# What is the correct "noun-verb" order when preceded by "only when"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, subject-verb-inversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sentences using: [something] + have + they](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/sentences-using-something-have-they)
>   [Inversion in “Only when the virus introduces its nucleic acid into a cell does disease occur”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76202/inversion-in-only-when-the-virus-introduces-its-nucleic-acid-into-a-cell-does-d)

In a sentence like this:

> Only when a gun is reliable, accurate and durable, **do I** trust my life to it.

Why do we swap "I do" into "do I"? Would both options be correct? I can't help myself but start parsing the last sentence as a question when the word order is as is.